# Entity Framework - query all records across linking tables

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm getting lost down the rabbit-hole of EF and Lambdas. I'm trying to get all records from across linking tables.

I'm pretty sure my question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991584/entity-framework-query-across-multiple-levels-of-relationship) but I can't work out how to apply the answer to my situation.

Here's a simplified model layout of my db.

[image: Simplified DB Model]

I'm trying to get a list of all the Speakers for a given event but can't work out how to build the Linq / Lambdas.

To be clear:

- An Event can have zero, one or many Sessions
- A Session can have zero, one or many Speakers
- A Speaker can talk in more than one Session or Event

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically after staring at the problem for over an hour and then posting here I think I've worked it out.

```
context.SessionSpeakers.Where(x => x.Session.EventId == odv.EventId).Select(x => x.Speaker);
```

I'll leave this here in case this helps someone else or anyone wants to offer a better answer.

Comment: Actually you don't even need the final Select(). It is redundant.